# PHP mail() function with html form does not send email

Tags: php, html, email

Have tried to make this code work, it does not give any PHP errors in the error log but it still does not succeed to send an email. Any ideas what could be wrong here? I seem to be stuck.

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['namn'];
$epost = $_POST['epost'];
$tfn = $_POST['tfn'];
$msg = $_POST['msg'];
$from = 'Från: B&P Kund';
$to = 'doggepe@hotmail.com';
$subject = 'Kontakt';

//Anger vad meddelandet ska innehålla
$body = "From: $name\n E-post: $epost\n Telefonnummer: $tfn\n Meddelande:\n $msg";

//När 'Skicka' klickas, genomför funktion nedan
if ($_POST['send']) {
   if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
      echo '<p class="btext" style="color:red;margin-left:25px;"> Ditt meddelande har skickats!</p>';
   }
//Felmeddelande om något inte fungerar som det ska
   else {
      echo '<p class="btext"> Något har gått fel, försök igen.</p>';
   }
}
?>
```

Here is the HTML code for the form:

```
<form method="post" action="">
Namn:<br><input type="text" name="namn" id="name"><br>
E-post:<br><input type="text" name="epost" id="epost"><br>
Telefonnummer:<br><input type="text" name="tfn" id="tfn"><br>
Meddelande:<br><textarea name="msg" id="msg"></textarea><br>
<input type="submit" name="send" value="Skicka" id="send"><br><br>
</form>
```

Comment: The form `action=""` is empty.

Comment: Does the `mail()` statement get executed at all?  What is the mail server's response?

Comment: Yes David, the screen prints the first first echo in the if statement when i click the send button.

Comment: Maihan, i have it that way because i have the script written directly inside the html file right by the form

Comment: Problem solved, the problem was that i had not activated the one.com mail server, this apparently needs to be set for the specific computer to receive emails from their server specifically.